# WebView doesn't respond to my keyboard input?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, webview

I'm writing some app for mac.
Here's the problem:

If I pull out an put `NSTextField` and WebView on the window, and connect `NSTextField` with WebView's method `takeStringURLFrom:`, they acts correctly. **I can type on everything in the WebView!** But, if I load the site with `loadRequest:` like this:

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"blah"]]];
```

WebView doesn't respond to my keyboard input.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777490/how-to-make-webview-osx-xcode-project-load-a-url-on-launch/4778236#4778236   This is the second one I explained. This doesn't respond to keyboard input.

Comment: do you mean that after you load a request manually you can't type in the text field anymore?